# SSH request timeout every time

Tags: macos, terminal, network, ssh

I am trying to access a storage space we have at work via ssh but I get a **timeout** every single time (*Mac OS 10.7.5 - Terminal*).

I checked firewalls, settings, even turned off Little Snitch, and port 22 is nowhere blocked. Doing the exact same request on a Windows machine with a SSH client works like a charm.

**Request:**

```
ssh login_name@server_address
```

**Answer:**

```
ssh: connect to host server_address port 22: Operation timed out
```

The problem seems to come from my company's vpn/proxy settings. Will update if I find a way around it.

Comment: Does it work if you shut your firewall down? I know you checked settings, but it does not say if you checked it with firewall *off*

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear, I did check with the firewall off as well !

Comment: I'm thinking of a routing issue... Is it possible to set your Mac to use the Windows computer's IP address and try to `ssh` from your Mac? Is the IP address configured with DHCP? Could you add the output of `netstat -rn` to your question (you may not want to make all IP addresses public here at AskDifferent, in that case replace them with `a.b.c.d` but **be consistent** so that the same IP address always gets the same `a.b.c.d` replacement)?  Is your Mac in the same network as your storage device?

Comment: Did you finally understand and fixed this `ssh` blocked?

Comment: @Anas: you wrote in a comment that the problem was the same on your colleague's laptop. Was this wrong? What is the difference between you Mac and Windows client? What does a basic `ping` give on the 2 ones?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Yes I did, but that was a Mac laptop as well. It worked on the PCs from other colleagues.

Comment: Understood. Please add to your original question the output of a basic `ping` on compared machines.

Comment: Please add to your OQ (Original Question) how are physically connected the Mac and the PC.

Comment: @danielAzuelos This was over 3 years ago :) All I can remember is that the issue ended up being with the company proxy blocking us, or something similar to that, as I said in one of my comments. Wish I could add more info!

Comment: I understood that, but today there are still many colleagues who look at this question because they have the same kind of problem to troubleshoot. This question won't go to the bin today :).

Answer (score 17):

3 commands may help you to track down this protocol failure:

```
ping server_address
traceroute server_address
ssh -v login_name@server_address
```

Please check that you are connecting to your targeted server with the
right network interface. If you are using the infamous `Automatic` location you might be networking the **wrong** way (for example through the neighbour free wi-Fi when you thought you were using your company VPN).

If you suspect a legitimate or accidental filtering, you will be able to
diagnose it with:

```
nmap -Pn -p22 server_address
```

Comment: Hi daniel, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I just realized that it might be a problem with my company's server settings and proxies, as it doesn't work on my colleague's laptop either.
Will let you know if it's not !
Thank you !

Comment: From another comment, this laptop is also a Mac.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos Is -Pn necessary for nmap? What difference would it make?

Comment: zsh: command not found: nmap

Comment: @JamieHutber which version of MacOS X? `echo ${PATH}`? [return] In fact I think you should make a question about your problem which isn't an `ssh timeout` one.

Comment: I am facing same issue after latest update of Mac, all three command I tried they are working, but when nmap is tried it gives State as 'filtered'? I am able o connect the same server with same network from windows. Can any one please help

Comment: Which computer did you update? Is this the `ssh` client or the server or both? What kind of equipment do you have between the client and the server?

Answer (score 3):

This occurred for me immediately after installing an updated version of OS X. Before you dig too deep into changing network settings I suggest doing an additional restart. This corrected the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing my DNS settings from the default ISP supplied ones to different ones (in this case 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1)

Comment: How does changing a public DNS server to another public DNS server fix a problem that’s localized (“here at work”, per the OP) to an internal network?

Comment: Exactly what I'm wondering as well. But no other variables were changed so it's odd.

Comment: My ISP does some very sketchy and restrictive stuff when it comes to routing my traffic.